# Write compare function to qsort to order array of structs by specified field?

Tags: c, struct, qsort

I have the following struct:

```
struct Variant{
    char name[50];
    int age;
    long long int temporal_aura;
    char timeline[50];
    char status;
};
```

I'll have an array of structs and I want to sort it by any of the fields above (name, age, temporal_aura, timeline, status). The field used to sort the array will be given by the user. For example:

```
void sort_struct(Variant **variants, int n, char *field){
    if(!strcmp(field,"name"))
        qsort(variants, n, sizeof(Variant), compare);

    if(!strcmp(field,"age"))
        qsort(variants, n, sizeof(Variant), compare);

    if(!strcmp(field,"temporal_aura"))
        qsort(variants, n, sizeof(Variant), compare);

    if(!strcmp(field,"timeline"))
        qsort(variants, n, sizeof(Variant), compare);

    if(!strcmp(field,"status"))
        qsort(variants, n, sizeof(Variant), compare);
}
```

My problem is: will I have to write a compare function to each member of the struct? Is there any way to optimize a compare function to this code?

Comment: note that `!strcmp()` is highly cryptic. The `!` operator makes it easy to misread that's a not-equal comparison. Use `strcmp(...) == 0` instead

Comment: Depending on your platform (Linux+glibc, not sure what else), you might have `qsort_r()`, which lets you pass an extra argument to the comparison function that you can use to tell it which field to compare...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> will I have to write a compare function to each member of the struct?

Yes.
(Unless you want a dirty "pass info in a global variable" solution).

Research `qsort_r()` for a `qsort()` alternative.

---

BTW, I would have expected `qsort(variants, n, sizeof(Variant*), compare);` (note: the `*`) or better as `qsort(variants, n, sizeof *variants, compare);`

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I was kinda unsure if my approach to the problem was right because many times I still think that "more lines = less quality". Appreciate the corrections to the qsort() call too! Thanks.